# How to use record-syntax with Yesod-Persistent

Tags: haskell, yesod

Why doesn't the following work? I kinda know that there's a lot going under the hood and the `User` type probably doesn't really have the `email`, `createdAt`, and `updatedAt` field. What's the best way to NOT instantiate objects using positional parameters, which can easily go out of hand?

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
User
  email String
  createdAt UTCTime Maybe default=CURRENT_TIME
  updatedAt UTCTime Maybe default=CURRENT_TIME
  deriving Show
]]

main :: IO ()
main = runSqlite ":memory:" $ do
  runMigration migrateAll
  u <- insert $ User {email="saurabhnanda@gmail.com" createdAt=Nothing updatedAt=Nothing}
```

Compilation errors:

```
trysql.hs:38:23:
    ‘email’ is not a (visible) field of constructor ‘User’

trysql.hs:38:55:
    ‘createdAt’ is not a (visible) field of constructor ‘User’

trysql.hs:38:74:
    ‘updatedAt’ is not a (visible) field of constructor ‘User’
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function names would be like: `userEmail`, `userCreatedAt`, `userUpdatedAt`.

Running cabal REPL and browsing the project help identify Yesod generated functions for persistent types.